# compare regular expression with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings with a set size, for instance:

1. ATTG
2. ATGC
3. ATNG
4. ATTN

A, T, G and C are always the same, but N can take on every value.
So i wanted to change them to regular expression:

1. ATTG
2. ATGC
3. AT[ATCG]G
4. ATT[ATCG]

And now i want to be able to say: value 1,3 and 4 are equal, and value 2 is unique. But how can you compare two regular expression to see if they are equal?

i am currently programming in python 2.7, but if other languages are able to give the me results, i am willing to switch or run the code from command line.

Comment: Which 2 Regular expressions are you referring to ?

Comment: yeah, that isnt clear here. so i want to compare each item in the list, if they can be combined, combine them, and check next value in list. and the list is ordered by the least number of N at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it yourself, since you are not actually using regular expression. I guess you just only want to compare two sequences.

```
def match(a,b):
    if a==b or a=='N' or b=='N':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def compare(str1,str2):
    if len(str1)!=len(str2):
        return False
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        if not match(str1[i],str2[i]):
            return False
    return True

print compare('ATTG','ATNG')
# True
print compare('ATTN','ATGC')
# False
```

Comment: so stupid, i didnt think of this. thank you very much!